# How to add password validation using regular expression in angular 8 with some conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular8

I want to validate a password entered by the user for the following criteria :

Password should be at least 8 characters as min and 20 as max and should contain one number, one capitalized character, and one special character within this only ,`./<>?;':"[]{}\|!@#$%^&*(-=_+ (.`

For it I used following regular expression :

`Password:`['', [Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*#?^&+=,.-])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?^&+=,.-].{8,}')]]``

Comment: What is your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can add your pattern by following two steps:

- In HTML file

  ```
  <div *ngIf="f.Password.errors.required">
    This field is mandatory</div>
  <div *ngIf="f.Password.errors.minlength">
    Must be at least 8 digits</div>
  <div *ngIf="f.Password.errors.maxlength">
    Must be Max 20 digits</div>
  <div *ngIf="f.Password.errors.pattern">
    Must contain at least 1 Special Character!</div>
  ```
- In ts file

  Password: [null,
          [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(8),
            Validators.maxLength(20),
            Validators.pattern(/[ !@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};':"\|,.<>/?][a-zA-Z0-9 ]/)
          ]]

**Run Demo** - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shhd1i

Answer (score 0):

It is called pattern validation. You can check this link https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator to see angular example. When you put "pattern" attribute (takes regEx) to element it will work as a validator.

```
<input name="firstName" ngModel pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern like:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z][A-Z])(?=.*[//,.?;<>:!@#$%^&*(-=_+)|{}\[\]])([a-zA-Z0-9//,.?;<>\':\"!@#$%^&*(-=_+)|{}\[\]]{8,20})$/
```

1. `^` The password string will start this way
2. `(?=.*[A-Z])`   The string must contain at least 1 uppercase
       alphabetical character
3. `(?=.*[0-9])`   The string must contain at least 1 numeric character
4. `(?=.*[//,.?;<>':"!@#$%^&*(-=_+)|{}\[\]])`  The string must contain at least one special
   character
5. `(?=.{8,20})`   The string must be eight characters to Maximum 20 characters

In angular 8 you can use

```
<input name="password" ngModel pattern="/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z][A-Z])(?=.*[//,.?;<>:!@#$%^&*(-=_+)|{}\[\]])([a-zA-Z0-9//,.?;<>\':\"!@#$%^&*(-=_+)|{}\[\]]{8,20})$/">
```

I think this can help..

Comment: But, its not accepting these special characters <>|\[]{}., so its not working properly.

Comment: @KRISHJACKMAN I have updated my answer. so you can check it.